# In Javascript, how to know the characters which are not supported with current font and displaying as boxes in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, angular, unicode

I have functionality similarly like "Windows character map" in my web application (Angular/JavaScript).
Displaying characters by Unicode with help of java script function "String.fromCharCode(Unicode)". as I need to support most of character sets available in the world, some characters are displaying as square boxes "" because of font not supported, here I need to disable the character (every character is displayed in span tag), I need to know is there any clue to check the boxed or unsupported characters in JavaScript/angular/html.

Comment: I doubt there is any way to do that; this font rendering happens way beyond the point of what you have access to using any scripting.

Comment: There is [this proposal](https://github.com/WICG/local-font-access) which should be able to let you check this out, but it's for the future only (or behind a flag in Chrome) and still requires some parsing on your part. An other solution would be to draw it on a canvas and analyze the resulting image, though it may not be trivial to make it correctly....